# С чем связано такое поведение сокращенной функции?

Tags: javascript, ооп

Есть класс, в котором определены некоторые свойства и метод (в котором закоментированный код работает правильно, а сокращенный вариант выдает *undefined* ), далее создаю наследственный объект, на котором проверяю работу функции. С чем связана некорректная работа сокращенного варианта ?

```js
class User {
  constructor(username, password) {
    this.username = username
    this.password = password
  }
  validatePassword() {
    this.password.length > 6 ? true : false
    // if (this.password.length > 6){
    //     return true
    // }
    // return false
  }
}

const Vanya = new User('vanya', 'golovasha350')
console.log(Vanya.validatePassword())
```

Comment: `return this.password.length > 6`. Тернарный оператор тут не нужен

Answer (score 2):

Напишите `return` перед `this.password.length`.